# Как разработать интерфейс к игре типа шахмат?

Tags: c++

Хочу написать на С++ игру типа шахмат таким образом, чтобы можно было нажимать на фигуру на доске и после этого ходить ею. К сожалению, из графических библиотек знаком только с graphics.h, однако в ней ничего подобного не наблюдалось. Подскажите, как возможно такое реализовать (желательно чтобы работало под DevCpp или Code Blocks).

Comment: Не понимаю людей которые минусуют вопрос и даже не пытаются аргументировать что им не нравится .

Comment: Мне кажется, в игре типа шахмат алгоритм во много раз сложнее кода, нужного для отображения. Начните с него.

Comment: Действительно, в graphics.h нет функции "нажать на фигуру на доске и после этого ходить". Шутка у нас на работе была, когда парень не смог решить дифф. уравнение в MathLab'e и спросил: "Где тут кнопка "решить дифф. уравнение"?"

Comment: @VladD , я собираюсь делать игру для 2 людей поэтому единственная проблема это отображение . Может позже займусь и компьютерным противником но сейчас больше волнует именно это .

Comment: @ArchDemon , я имел ввиду что там нету ничего для отслеживания нажатий и т.д. (или я про это не знаю ).

Comment: Шашки для начала сделай, там рисование попроще - квадрат и круг.

Answer (score 3):

Несмотря на то, что ваш вопрос очень простой, дать на него ответ нелегко. Дело в том, что он слишком общий. Непонятно, каким вы видите свой интерфейс, как планируете выводить рисунки на экран, как будете развивать программу, какой у вас опыт программирования.

Вашу задачу можно довольно легко решить при помощи какой-либо из распространённых библиотек для создания графических интерфейсов. Если вы хотите использовать C++, то можете взять wxWidgets, Qt (очень мощный фреймворк, но чуть сложнее компилировать программу в сторонних IDE), Gtk. Все они умеют выводить изображения на экран (в том числе и сохранённые в форматах PNG, JPEG и т. д.), обрабатывать щелчки мышью. По ним много документации в том числе и на русском.

Также, если установите стороннее ПО, то сможете нарисовать графический интерфейс мышью, а программа сама сгенерирует нужный код.

Если вы пишете программу, чтобы попрактиковаться так как интересуетесь разработкой игр, то вам, возможно, будет полезно изучить библиотеку OpenGL (или DirectX, хотя их возможности практически равны).

И так далее. Библиотек огромное количество. Если уточните критерии, то мы сможем подобрать что-то вам по душе.

Comment: каких-то особых требований и нет . желательно чтобы можно было быстро разобраться без каких-либо предварительных знаний . Интерфейс вижу как просто поле 8 на 8 (и возможно 2-3 какие-то кнопки но это не особо важно ) . Важно просто чтобы написать простенькую рабочую программу а потом уже сам разберусь . Если можно киньте ссылку на  какой-то туториал (на русском так как с английским беда) .

Comment: Сложно сходу что-то посоветовать. Попробуйте для начала установить QtCreator (это бесплатно) и в нём набросать графический интерфейс. По нему есть [учебник](http://www.altlinux.org/images/4/4b/Book-qtC%2B%2B.pdf). Правда, он ориентирован на начинающих изучать C++, поэтому сразу переходите к 11 главе.
Если не понравится, то пишите, а лучше сформулируйте всё же список требований к библиотеке и среде разработки и задайте вопрос. Мы вам что-то подберём!

Answer (score 2):

Если вы не знаете графических библиотек или фреймворков, но очень хотите сделать графическую игру, то надо эти самые библиотеки и фреймворки изучить. И да, единственное, что вам не хватает в graphics.h - это получение координат нажатой кнопки мыши. А это можно найти в интернете: GetCursorPos().

---

P.S. А вам нужны ответы или оценки? Советую не обращать внимания на них, если они не аргументированы и сосредоточится на решение куда более важных задач... например, на создание суперкомпьютеров.

Comment: А каким образом отслеживать нажатие кнопки мыши?

Comment: Точно, про клики я забыл, это будет посложнее: [Reading Input Buffer Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685035.aspx). Как бы то ни было, я бы на вашем месте приступил к изучению библиотек, которые предназначены для этого, вместо забивания гвоздей хлебом. Заодно у Вас и цель есть.

Answer (score -1):

При каждом клике мыши нужно отслеживать куда был сделан клик (позиция мыши). По позиции мыши можно понять на какую фигуру мы нажали (если на неё попали) т.к. у каждой фигуры есть площать (min max координата по x и у). Далее у той фигуры на которую мы попали порождаем событие, которое в последствии обработаем

Comment: идея мне и так понятна но я совершенно не знаком с функциями которые позволяют это делать .

Answer (score -1):

Берете к примеру SFML, в вашем случае проблем не будет. В туториалах есть работа с Code::Blocks. По возможностям будет задел на будущее, да и не будет проблем с отображением.

Посмотрите на пример: http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/